# cookies path " / " in my application hosted in Azure app service

Tags: .net, azure, path, session-cookies, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have hosted my application built in .net over Azure app.

We have some cookies which are system/app generated. Some cookies shows path "/" which is not accepted in testing.

We tried to change path but it is working for application (custom user defined cookies) cookies.

Can we change this path "/ " as it means (may be means) /site/wwwroot in Azure app service.
Or can you please suggest some standard practice which we can follow here.

Hope this information is enough.

Regards
Kunal

Comment: So you have multiple apps hosted as virtual applications in one App Service?

Comment: @juunas Nope. It is Single application in one of Azure app service plan.

Comment: Then why is the path a problem?

Comment: as per testing report they said there should not any cookies path as "/" So what i know if it is stand alone app in app service plan then there is no harm. What you say

Answer (score 0):

A cookie that has path `"/"` means it is sent with all requests to the domain name.

One of the reasons to specify the path is if you are hosting multiple apps under the same domain name, and only want to use the cookie with one of them.

It does not seem to be the case here, and the path should be fine.
Actually your app might stop working if you specify another path as it would not be sent to the root of your app.

You can read more on how cookies work and their parameters on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies.

Comment: Ok. So on Azure app service each app is hosted under azurewebsites.net domain.
Like myapp1.azurewebsites.net is having app service plan P1.
Another user is having hisapp1.azurewebsites.net. So it can use these cookies. Is it?
Note: I have used custom domain for my app. www.myapp.com which is redirecting CNAME to clud URL myapp1.azurewebsites.net.

So this custom domain use can affect this cookies issue?

Sorry as I am new to this cookies world.
Thanks again juunas for prompt reply

Comment: Yeah, and any cookies created in that app will only be sent to myapp1.azurewebsites.net unless otherwise specified.